# Performance implications of using inter-process communication (IPC)

Tags: linux, windows, macos, performance, ipc

What type of usage is IPC intended for and is it is OK to send larger chunks of JSON (hundreds of characters) between processes using IPC? Should I be trying to send as tiny as message as possible using IPC or would the performance gains coming from reducing message size not be worth the effort?

Comment: I am also interested in this, I send images in a format of data URL, which might be up to 1 mb size.

Comment: This is *extremely* dependent on the OS and the IPC technology. A generic answer covering Windows, Linux and OS X is impossible.

Answer (score 7):

> What type of usage is IPC intended for and is it is OK to send larger chunks of JSON (hundreds of characters) between processes using IPC?

At it's core, IPC is what it says on the tin. It's a tool to use when you need to communicate information between processes, whatever that may be. The topic is very broad, and technically includes allocating shared memory and doing the communication manually, but given the tone of the question, and the tags, I'm assuming you're talking about the OS provided facilities.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) does a pretty good job discussing how IPC is used, and I don't think I can do much better, so I'll concentrate on the second question.

> Should I be trying to send as tiny as message as possible using IPC or would the performance gains coming from reducing message size not be worth the effort?

This smells a bit like a micro-optimization.  I can't say definitively, because I'm not privy to the source code at Microsoft and Apple, and I really don't want to dig through the Linux kernel's implementation of IPC, but, here's a couple points:

1. IPC is a common operation, so OS designers are likely to optimize it for efficiency. There are teams of engineers that have considered the problem and figured out how to make this fast.
2. The bottleneck in communication across processes/threads is almost always synchronization. Delays are bad, but race conditions and deadlocks are worse. There are, however, lots of creative ways that OS designers can speed up the procedure, since the system controls the process scheduler and memory manager.
3. There's lots of ways to make the data transfer itself fast. For the OS, if the data needs to cross process boundaries, then there is some copying that may need to take place, but the OS copies memory all over the place all the time. Think about a command line utility, like `netstat`. When that executable is run, memory needs to be allocated, the process needs to be loaded from disk, and any address fixing that the OS needs to do is done, before the process can even start. This is done so quickly that you hardly even notice. On Windows `netstat` is about 40k, and it loads into memory almost instantly. (Notepad, another fast loader is 10 times that size, but it still launches in a tiny amount of time.)
4. The big exception to #2 above is if you're talking about IPC between processes that aren't on the same computer. (Think Windows RPC) Then you're really bound by the speed of the networking/communication stack, but at that point a few kb here or there isn't going to make a whole lot of difference. (You could consider AJAX to be a form of IPC where the 'processes' are the server and your browser. Now consider how fast Google Docs operates.)

If the IPC is between processes on the same system,  I don't think that it's worth a ton of effort shaving bytes from your message. Make your message easy to debug.

In the case that the communication is happening between processes on different machines, then you may have something to think about, having spent a lot of time debugging issues that would have been simple with a better data format, a few dozen extra milliseconds transit time isn't worth making the data harder to parse/debug. Remember the three rules of optimization<sup>1</sup>:

1. Don't.
2. Don't... yet. (For experts)
3. Profile before you do.

---

*<sup>1</sup> The first two rules are usually attributed to Michael Jackson. ([This one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_A._Jackson_(computer_scientist)) not [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_Jackson))*